# Used Win install...Ubuntu won't start

Tags: system-installation

I used the Windows install feature...spent an hour attempting to setup.
After a long time I got "compliz closed unexpectedly" and "unable to mount floppy drive."

I'd sure like to use Ubuntu but it has to be made simpler.

Comment: What is not clear  for the moment, if u be able to boot or not?

Comment: Could you please add some hardware info and which windows is being used as well as confirming that there was unallocated or free space to install Ubuntu was available or not at install time?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is very easy to try. You can you the LiveCD or a LiveUSB stick:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Basically, just download the ISO file from Canonical for your architecture and follow the instructions from the given link.

As for actually installing Ubuntu, I do not recommend the Windows install feature. You should use a virtual machine (like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) which is free) to host Ubuntu.

The previous solutions are very simple and very good. However, they will always be slower than normal. First because reading from a USB stick or a CD is a lot slower than reading from a hard drive. Second, because you are emulating an operating system on top of another operating system.

If you truly want to take the full benefit of using Ubuntu, you should install it alongside Windows, there is no question about it.
How to do so properly? Well, it's easy:

1. Backup your Windows stuff. Just in case you mess up.
2. Create a LiveCD or LiveUSB of Ubuntu and run it.
3. Use the GParted program in the Live version and:
  1. Shrink one of your partitions to create space for an Ubuntu Partition. You can shrink the Windows partition or any other, just make sure you have like 10GB free.
  2. Shrink another partition to have enough free space for the "swap" partition. This partition should have the same size as your RAM. In my ASUS computer I have 3GB of RAM, so my swap partition is 3GB.
4. Once these 2 partitions are created you can install Ubuntu. You should choose the advanced mode of installation to make sure the system uses the partitions you created. The Ubuntu Partition should be ext4 and should be "/" (root) while the swap partition doesn't really matter.
5. Restart and enjoy!

Note: You can also shrink and increase partitions using Windows:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Note 2: You don't actually have to create 2 partitions. IIRC, if you shrink a partition without doing anything else the installer will detect it and will try to use it for Ubuntu, while making all the configurations automatically (easy install mode). I am however shaky with the easy install (haven't used in a long time) so could anyone confirm? xD

I just prefer GParted because it is a more powerful tool.

If you have problems with your boot (if you can't boot) I strongly suggest using [Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)! (seriously, it does wonders)
and if you want to make full backup of your disks / partitions, I suggest using [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/)!